# Two buttons display same div. One button has more visibility of options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have two `<input type=Button>`. When clicked, both will load one dialogue box contained inside a div.

I want to add a separate button and text into the div which is only viewable when the second button is clicked.  Instead of rewriting this one for btn one and one for btn two.  How can I make the extra text and button only available if the 2nd btn is clicked?

```html
<div id="LabourOrPlantDialog" title="Comments" style="display:none;">
   <table class="table">
      <tr>
         <th>Item</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td id="Item"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <br />
   <textarea id="ExistingComments" type="text" runat="server" rows="7" cols="30" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
   <input id="SubmitComment" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitButton()" />

   <!-- BELOW IS THE TEXT AND BTN I ONLY WANT AVAILABLE WHEN 2ND BTN IS CLICKED -->

   <input type="text" name="BoqTextBox" />
   <input type="AddValueButton" value="+" onclick="Add(BoqTextBox)" />                          
</div>
```

Some sort of bool im guessing? Have never done this before...any help would be great. Thanks

---

EDIT:

```
<input id="SubmitCommentsForOne" type="button" value="Comments" onclick="ShowComment('<%: item.ItemCode %>')" />

<input id="SubmitCommentsForTwo" type="button" value="Comments" onclick="ShowComment('<%: item.Number %>')" />
```

```js
var Code
function ShowCommentBoxForBOQ(Number) {
   Code = Number;
   Work.DisplayBoxForBOQ(Number);
   $("#LabourOrPlantDialog").dialog({ modal: true });
}
```

`LabourOrPlantDialog` loads the div.

---

EDIT: Can I give anything else which would help? Does anyone have any idea a tall?  Thank you for any replies

Comment: Where's your functional code?

Comment: We need the code for the functions inside the `onclick` attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add this wherever you'd like the new text & button:

   ```
   <div id="hiddenBox">
     <input type="text" name="BoqTextBox" />
     <input type="button" value="+" onclick="Add(BoqTextBox);" /> 
   </div>
   ```
2. Add this somewhere in your stylesheet:

   ```
   #hiddenBox{display:none;}
   ```
3. Add this somewhere in your javascript

   ```
   $("#SubmitCommentsForTwo").click(function(){
       $("#hiddenBox").show();  
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply shooter...looks good..but how I call (part 3) in the JS only when button 2 is clicked? As both are calling onclick="ShowComment('<%: necessary bind %>')

How can I ref to run part 3?

Comment: No problem. I just noticed you are using jQuery. Please see my updated javascript, which takes care of your question